# extjs 4.1 grid hangs on loading - random

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I hope there is a solution for my issue. I'm using Extjs 4.1.  I have a viewport with a panel that allows to enter search parameters at the top and 2 tabs at the botton.  Both tabs have grids.  The grids on both tabs are very similar in the set up (not the data).

The grids support remote sorting and filtering and one also supports grouping. Both grids have stores with autoload = false, take 2 extra parameters (date and type), buffered = true and pageSize = 100.

Proxy type is rest.
Both grids are loaded at the same time when a search button in the top panel is clicked.  Search parameters are passed as extra parameters.

I set the ajax time out to 10 minutes.

Sometimes when I click the search button at the top, one of the grids is stack with the Loading mask. Log file shows the controller is called and returns results fine. Looks like when the json is parced - the grid loading is halted.
I won't be able to upgrade to a new version at this point.

Any suggestions?  May be how to detect when the load is hang and try again?
Thank you.

EDIT:  Seems to be happening almost every time if I press search button and while I see loading mask on one of the tabs, I witch to another tab very fast.  If that tab hasn't finished loading, it will get stuck in that position.

EDIT:  Added some code - basically any time load() is called on a store - this could happen.

```
index.cshtml
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.require([
        'Ext.container.Viewport',
        'Ext.grid.*',
        'Ext.form.*',
        'Ext.Date.*',
        'Ext.ux.CheckColumn',
        'FICMTB.ui.PanelForSearch',
        'FICMTB.ui.ManagerSearchResultsCancelTabPanel',
        'FICMTB.ui.ManagerSearchResultsLateTabPanel'
    ]);

    Ext.onReady(function () {
        initialize();
    });

    function initialize() {
        Ext.Ajax.timeout = 60000; // 60 seconds

        var searchPanel = Ext.create('FICMTB.ui.PanelForSearch');
        var searchResultsCancelPanel = Ext.create('FICMTB.ui.ManagerSearchResultsCancelTabPanel');
        var searchResultsLatePanel = Ext.create('FICMTB.ui.ManagerSearchResultsLateTabPanel');
        // tried to remove the loading - if the response already processed
        Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function (conn, resp, opts) {
            if (!Ext.Ajax.isLoading()) {
                searchResultsCancelPanel.grid.loadMask && searchResultsCancelPanel.grid.loadMask.hide();
            }
        });

        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            layout: 'fit',

            items: [{
                title: 'Cancel',
                layout: 'fit',
                xtype: 'container',
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                items: searchResultsCancelPanel 
            }, 
            {
                title: 'Late',
                layout: 'fit',
                xtype: 'container',
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto',
                items: searchResultsLatePanel 
            }]
        });

        searchPanel.on('searchTriggered', function (searchPanel, date, type) {
            searchResultsCancelPanel.date = date;
            searchResultsCancelPanel.type = type;
            searchResultsCancelPanel.load(date, type);

            searchResultsLatePanel.date = date;
            searchResultsLatePanel.type = type;
            searchResultsLatePanel.load(date, type);

        });

        var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                {
                    region: 'north',
                    title: 'Search Area',
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    split: false,
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    border: 0,
                    items: [searchPanel]
                },
                {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    height: 'auto',
                    region: 'center',
                    title: 'Trades',
                    items: [tabPanel]
                }

           ]
        });

    };

    </script>

this is one of the panels that have grids (second is pretty much the same and the problem could happen to either - I didn't realize that I don't need this panel and just use a grid -which is also a panel - but I'm not going to change it now if it doesn't help to solve the loading data issue.

ManagerSearchResultsCancelTabPanel.js

Ext.ns('FICMTB.ui');
Ext.define('FICMTB.ui.ManagerSearchResultsCancelTabPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    layout: { 
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch',
        pack: 'start'
    },


initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.grid = Ext.create('FICMTB.ui.ManagerTransactionsCancelGrid', {
        flex: 1
    });
    me.items = [me.grid];

    me.date = 'value';
    me.Type = 'value';

    me.callParent(arguments);
},

load: function (date, type) {
    var me = this;
    var store = me.grid.getStore();
    store.addExtraParam(date, type); 
}
});

ManagerTransactionsCancelGrid.js

Ext.Date.patterns = {
    ISO8601Long: "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    ISO8601Short: "Y-m-d",
    ShortDate: "n/j/Y",
    LongDate: "l, F d, Y",
    FullDateTime: "l, F d, Y g:i:s A",
    MonthDay: "F d",
    ShortTime: "g:i A",
    LongTime: "g:i:s A",
    SortableDateTime: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",
    UniversalSortableDateTime: "Y-m-d H:i:sO",
    YearMonth: "F, Y"
};

Ext.define('FICMTB.ui.DisableCheckColumn', {
   extend: 'Ext.ux.CheckColumn',
   alias: 'widget.disablecheckcolumn',

   processEvent: function (type, view, cell, recordIndex, cellIndex, e) {
    var enabled = Ext.query('[class*=disabled]', cell).length == 0,
        me = this;

    if (enabled) {
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
    },

});

Ext.define('Ext.form.field.DateDisplay', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Display',
    alias: 'widget.datedisplayfield',
    dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
    valueToRaw: function (value) {
        var me = this;
        return Ext.Date.format(value, me.dateFormat);
    },
    rawToValue: function (rawValue) {
        var me = this;
        return Ext.Date.parse(rawValue, me.dateFormat);
    }
});

Ext.ns('FICMTB.ui');

Ext.define('FICMTB.ui.ManagerTransactionsCancelModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'CancelId' },
    { name: 'Date' },
    { name: 'sort_alpha_key' },
    { name: 'cancel_ind' },
    { name: 'qty' },
    { name: 'prx' },
    { name: 'originator' },
    { name: 'comments' },
    { name: 'ErrorReason' },
    { name: 'ErrorSource' }
    ],
    idProperty: 'CancelId'
});

FICMTB.ui.managerEditFormInstance = Ext.create('FICMTB.ui.ManagerEditForm').hide();

Ext.define("FICMTB.ui.ManagerTransactionsCancelGrid", {
extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
requires: ['FICMTB.ui.ManagerTransactionsCancelModel',
            'Ext.ux.grid.RowActions',
            'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
            'Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter',
            'Ext.ux.grid.menu.ListMenu',
            'Ext.ux.grid.menu.RangeMenu'],
itemId: 'managerCancelGridId',
initComponent: function () {
    var me = this;

    me.columns = me.buildColumns();

    me.features = [Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
groupHeaderTpl: 'Cancel Info: {name} ({rows.length} Item{[values.rows.length > 1 ? "s" : ""]})',
    enableGroupingMenu: false
 })];

    me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'FICMTB.ui.ManagerTransactionsCancelModel',
        remoteSort: true,
        storeId: 'ManagerTransactionsCancelStoreId',
        autoLoad: false,
        buffered: true,
        groupField: 'sort_alpha_key',
        addExtraParam: function (date, type) {
            this.proxy.extraParams = this.proxy.extraParams || {};
            this.getProxy().extraParams.aDate = date;
            this.getProxy().extraParams.aType = type;
            this.proxy.applyEncoding(this.proxy.extraParams);
            this.load();
        },
        pageSize: 100,
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            timeout: 600000,

            url: '/Manager/ManagerCancelTransactions/',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'Transaction',
                totalProperty: "Total"
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'Transaction'
            }

        }
    });

    me.selModel = new Ext.selection.RowModel({
        singleSelect: true
    });
    me.dockedItems = me.buildDockedItems();
    me.autoSizeColumns = true;

    me.autoScroll = true;
    me.forcefit = true;

    me.callParent(arguments);
},

  showEditForm: function (rec) {
    var me = this;
    FICMTB.ui.managerEditFormInstance.setPosition(100, 100);

    FICMTB.ui.managerEditFormInstance.form.setActiveRecord(rec || null);
    FICMTB.ui.managerEditFormInstance.show();
 },
  // inline buttons
  buildDockedItems: function () {
    var me = this;
    return [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: 'Save All Changes',
            tooltip: 'Save All Changes',
            icon: '/./Content/images/save.gif',

            handler: function () {
                Ext.Msg.confirm('confirm', 'Save All Changes?', function (btn) {
                    if (btn !== 'yes')
                        return;
                    //alert("Save");
                    me.getStore().save();
                });

            }

        }, '-', {
            text: 'Approve All and Save',
            tooltip: 'Approve and Save All Changes',
            icon: '/./Content/images/add.png',

            handler: function (button, event) {
                Ext.Msg.confirm('confirm', 'Approve All and Save?', function (btn) {
                    if (btn !== 'yes')
                        return;
                     //alert("Save All");
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/Manager/ApproveAllTransactions/',
                        params: {
                            aDate: me.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.aDate,
                            aBondType: me.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.aBondType,
                            aTabType: "CANCEL"
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            me.getStore().load();
                        },
                        timeout: 60000
                    });
                });

            }

        }, '-', {
            itemId: 'DeclineAllSave',
            text: 'Decline All and Save',
            tooltip: 'Decline All Changes and Save',
            icon: '/./Content/images/delete_icon.png',
            handler: function (button, event) {
                Ext.Msg.confirm('confirm', 'Decline All and Save?', function (btn) {
                    if (btn !== 'yes')
                        return;
                    //alert("Decline and Save All Pressed");
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        timeout: 60000,
                        url: '/Manager/DeclineAllTransactions/',
                        params: {
                            aDate: me.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.aDate,
                            aBondType: me.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.aBondType,
                            aTabType: "CANCEL"
                        }, 
                        success: function (response) {
                            me.getStore().load();
                        }

                    });

                });
            }
        }]
    }];
  },

  buildColumns: function () {
    var me = this;

    return [
    { xtype: 'rowactions', hidden: true, hideable: false,
        actions: [{}],
        keepSelection: true,
        groupActions: [{
            iconCls: 'icon-grid',
            qtip: 'Action on Group',
            align: 'left',
            callback: function (grid, records, action, groupValue) {
                me.showEditForm(records);
            }
        }]
    },
    { text: 'Date', dataIndex: 'Date', width: 70, sortable: true, 
      renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer(Ext.Date.patterns.ShortDate) },
    { text: 'cancel indicator',
        dataIndex: 'cancel_ind',
        sortable: true,
        width: 50,
        itemId: 'cancel_indId',
        xtype: 'disablecheckcolumn',
        listeners: {
            checkchange: function (column, recordIndex, checked) {
                var grid = column.findParentByType('grid'),
                    store = grid.getStore(),
                    record = store.getAt(recordIndex),
                    group = record.get("sort_alpha_key"),
                    groupRecords = store.query('sort_alpha_key', group);


                groupRecords.each(function (rec) {
                    rec.set('cancel_ind', checked);

                });
            }
        }
    },
    { text: 'sort_alpha_key', dataindex: 'ControlNumCusipCombination', hidden: true, 
      hideable: false },
    { text: 'qty', dataIndex: 'qty', width: 50, sortable: true },
    { text: 'prx', dataIndex: 'prx', width: 50, sortable: true },
    { text: 'originator', dataIndex: 'originator', width: 90, sortable: true },

    { text: 'comments', dataIndex: 'comments', width: 120, sortable: true },
    { text: 'Error Source', dataIndex: 'ErrorSource', sortable: true, width: 70 },
    { text: 'Error Reason', dataIndex: 'ErrorReason', sortable: true, width: 70 }];
 },
 width: 'auto'
 });
```

Comment: will probably need to show code to get an answer. JSfiddle if possible.

Comment: @dbrin added some code. thanks.

Comment: LOL, OK now there is too much code :) Can you make a smaller test case?

Comment: oh, and get rid of the fit layout config of the tab panel.

Comment: In general, when you're left stuck with a loading mask, that means that a javascript error has killed the execution at an unexpected point. Don't you have any error that appears in the console? Also, buffered stores are quite touchy in my experience, so does the problem remains if you disable buffering for the store?

Comment: I have a smaller test case, but I have no problem there.  It must be some combination of the elements that I use that messes things up.  It's random - not happening every time.

Comment: No errors on the console.  I'll try disabling buffering, but I believe I need it for the infinite scrolling.

Comment: I tried disabling buffering, I tried increasing the size of the page.  Most of the time the number of records is less than 200. Which should be nothing.  I made the page size 300.  It is still happening - randomly.

Comment: Seems to be happening almost every time I press search button and while I see loading mask on one of the tabs, I switch to another tab very fast.  If that tab hasn't finished loading, it will get stuck in that "loading"  state.